# Best way to handle multiple async calls and scope updates in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, hibernate

I'm facing a difficult situation where I have to filter out search results based on various filters on UI. 
[image: Dashboard with multiple filters]

Whenever I make a search, there is an api call which loads the results asynchronously. User can filter any number of times even before the results of previous search criteria loads.

```
httpService.get("getCREWRequests.do", filters.getValues()).then(function(data){
        $scope.requests=data;
});
```

I'm simply updating my scope with different results from api and showing them on screen.

However, api calls being asynchronous, the data for different search criteria can come at different times. And the records may change whenever api calls returns. So, at any point of time, it can't be guaranteed whether the results are correct as per the filter criteria that user selected at any specific moment.

How can I make sure that the results are always in sync with the filter criteria?

1. I can't load results synchronously because the api calls can be extremely slow sometimes and the user will have to wait for hours to see the results.
2. I can't load all the records in one shot and filter results on UI because of the number of records in the database and some other business constraints.
3. I can't improve the performance from backend because it will still not resolve the issue at hand.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Promise is a Promise. So, it will always the be resolved(resolve/reject), and the then() will always be called upon resolving.

To make sure that my latest call is execute we can maintain function call counter. The records would be changed, only if the it's latest call.

Here is a working sample:

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.result = 0;

  vm.loadCount = 0;
  vm.countToBeDisplayed = 0;

  vm.getResult = function(localLoadCount) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.info("localLoadCount: " + localLoadCount);
      console.info("vm.loadCount: " + vm.loadCount);
      deferred.resolve(localLoadCount);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10)) * 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
  };


  vm.loadTestMultipleLoadsPromise = null;

  vm.invokeTestMultipleLoads = function() {
    vm.loadCount++;
    var localLoadCount = vm.loadCount;
    vm.loadTestMultipleLoadsPromise = vm.getResult(localLoadCount);
    vm.loadTestMultipleLoadsPromise.then(function successCallback(response) {
      // Checking if loadCount matches the localLoadCount
      if (vm.loadCount === localLoadCount) {
        vm.result = response;
      }
    });
  };


}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="TestApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
    Result: {{vm.result}}
    <button ng-click="vm.invokeTestMultipleLoads()">call test method</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

vm.getResult(): Method is like you api call. It has random timeout, so we can expect it behave same as a slow api.

vm.invokeTestMultipleLoads(): This function is called from javascript/angualr. It would call the api internally.
loadCount is increased whenever this method is called. Note that we are only changing the results, only if the localCount matched the loadCount.

Comment: finally able to implement it in a lot simple way. The solution is quite similar to yours.